# How to return only part of a line with egrep

Tags: linux, unix, shell, grep

I have a program that returns something like this:

```
status: playing
artURL: http://beta.grooveshark.com/static/amazonart/m3510922.jpg
estimateDuration: 29400
calculatedDuration: 293000
albumName: This Is It
position: 7291.065759637188
artistName: Michael Jackson
trackNum: 13
vote: 0
albumID: 3510922
songName: Billie Jean
artistID: 39
songID: 24684170
```

I'm looking to extract the artist name and the song name from all this and I figured egrep would be a nice way to do it. The problem is that I have no idea how to return only part of the matching line and not the whole line.

`egrep "artistName"` obviously returns

```
artistName: Michael Jackson
```

I only need it to return

```
Michael Jackson
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to pipe the output to another program, like cut:

```
egrep ^artistName | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Or you could do the whole thing in awk or sed:

```
awk -F ': ' '/^artistName/ {print $2}'
sed -n '/^artistName/ {s/.*: //;p;}'
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `grep` which supports Perl regular expressions:

```
grep -Po '(?<=^artistName: ).*' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

your data is structured and has a distinct field delimiter (:), so you can use awk

```
awk '$1~/^(artistName|songName)/{print $2}' file
```